# How to deal with a sum in the denominator

Tags: inequality

In a book, I saw the following inequality:

$$e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2 (\lambda + \Delta)}}\leq e^{- \min\{\lambda, \frac{\lambda^2}{\Delta}\}/4},$$

for some (specific) $\lambda, \Delta \geq 0$

Does this hold for any such $\lambda, \Delta$ or is this a special property of how these two quantities are defined?

In general, how can I work with such quantities, when I have a sum in the denominator and I would like to get only the dominant term (exactly) and the remaining part possibly approximated?

Comment: Start from $\lambda+\Delta\leqslant2\max(\lambda,\Delta)$ and follow the lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging the original inequality:

$${-\frac{\lambda^2}{2 (\lambda + \Delta)}}\le {- \min\left\{\lambda, \frac{\lambda^2}{\Delta}\right\}\over 4}\\{2\frac{\lambda^2}{(\lambda + \Delta)}}\ge {\min\left\{\lambda, \frac{\lambda^2}{\Delta}\right\}}$$

If $\lambda, \Delta > 0$:

$$\begin{array}{cl}\lambda < \Delta \implies& {2\frac{\lambda^2}{(\lambda + \Delta)}} > {2\frac{\lambda^2}{2\Delta}} = \frac{\lambda^2}{\Delta} = \min\left\{\lambda, \frac{\lambda^2}{\Delta}\right\}\\
\lambda > \Delta \implies& {2\frac{\lambda^2}{(\lambda + \Delta)}} > {2\frac{\lambda^2}{2\lambda}} = \lambda =\min\left\{\lambda, \frac{\lambda^2}{\Delta}\right\}\\
\lambda = \Delta \implies& {2\frac{\lambda^2}{(\lambda + \Delta)}} = \lambda =\min\left\{\lambda, \frac{\lambda^2}{\Delta}\right\}\end{array}$$

The inequality holds for $\lambda, \Delta > 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Does a similar Thing also hold for 3 or more summands?

Comment: @user136457 Thank you for the question. I'm not quite sure what sort of inequality we would be dealing with if it were 3 summands. You could ask another question and specify it there.

Comment: @user136457 Sorry, I noticed I had only partially answered the question, considering only positive values. I have edited the answer so that every real $\lambda$ and $\Delta$ is considered. Please notify me if there are mistakes.

Comment: So, I am intersted in only $\lambda, \Delta \geq 0$, so this shouldn't be an issue. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @user136457 Oh dear, I did not see that in the question... I should stop using this site when I am tired.